# omp parallel for raises segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, openmp, nested-loops

I'm facing with an annoying segfault error, in a nested loop, I want to parallelize the outmost loop, with the following #pragma directives:

```
calculate_kernels(double *ux, double *uy, double *ux_total, double *uy_total)
{
    complex<double> Phi_left, IPhi_left, IPsi_left;
    complex<double> Phi_right, IPhi_right, IPsi_right;
    complex<double> B, B_left, B_right;
    double kappa = 3. - 4. * _nu;
    complex<double> s, mid, ds;

#pragma omp parallel for private(Phi_left, IPhi_left, IPsi_left, Phi_right, IPhi_right, IPsi_right)
    for (int is = 0; is < _number_subfaults; is++)
    {

        ds = pow((_right_node_x_y[is] - _left_node_x_y[is]) * conj(_right_node_x_y[is] - _left_node_x_y[is]), 0.50);
        s = (_right_node_x_y[is] - _left_node_x_y[is]) / ds;
        B = _slip_r_t[is] * _mu / 4. / M_PI / (1. - _nu);
        B_left = -B;
        B_right = +B;
        mid = 0.5 * (_left_node_x_y[is] + _right_node_x_y[is]);

        for (int irr = 0; irr < _number_station; irr++)
        {
            _station_r_t_midfault[irr] = (_station_x_y[irr] - mid) * conj(s);
        }

        _left_node_r_t_midfault[is] = (_left_node_x_y[is] - mid) * conj(s);
        _right_node_r_t_midfault[is] = (_right_node_x_y[is] - mid) * conj(s);

        for (int ir = 0; ir < _number_station; ir++)
        {

            Phi_left = -1i * B_left / (_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _left_node_r_t_midfault[is]);
            IPhi_left = -1i * B_left * log(_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _left_node_r_t_midfault[is]);
            IPsi_left = 1i * conj(B_left) * log(_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _left_node_r_t_midfault[is]) + 1i * conj(_left_node_r_t_midfault[is]) * B_left / (_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _left_node_r_t_midfault[is]);

            Phi_right = -1i * B_right / (_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _right_node_r_t_midfault[is]);
            IPhi_right = -1i * B_right * log(_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _right_node_r_t_midfault[is]);
            IPsi_right = 1i * conj(B_right) * log(_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _right_node_r_t_midfault[is]) + 1i * conj(_right_node_r_t_midfault[is]) * B_right / (_station_r_t_midfault[ir] - _right_node_r_t_midfault[is]);

            Phi[ir] = Phi_left + Phi_right;
            IPhi[ir] = IPhi_left + IPhi_right;
            IPsi[ir] = IPsi_left + IPsi_right;

            A3[ir] = (1. / _mu) * (kappa * IPhi[ir] - _station_r_t_midfault[ir] * conj(Phi[ir]) - conj(IPsi[ir])) * s;

            ux[ir] = real(A3[ir]);
            uy[ir] = imag(A3[ir]);

            ux_total[ir] += ux[ir];
            uy_total[ir] += uy[ir];
        }
    }
}
```

With $OMP_NUM_THREADS grater than one, a segfault error occurs, while $OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 works fine.

I know this is very basic question for parallel-geeks, thank you if you can help me in resolving this.

Comment: where is the declaration of all those arrays? What is their size?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the declarations are fine, they are made outside of the function, the code is working by one thread.

Comment: just because it appears to work does not mean that it is free of UB. Chances are high that there is undefined behavior no matter what number of threads and with a single thread you are just unlucky and get no crash. Anyhow, without a [mcve] it is not possible to tell what is wrong with the code

Comment: Unless openmp is "magic" in some way I think you have race conditions. You seem to be writing to `_station_r_t_midfault` in the same positions from all threads

Comment: 1) you have many race conditions in this code. They have to be addressed, although I don't think they can give a segfault (but for sure unpredictable results); 2) assuming you have posted the full code of the routine, it looks like you are using global variables: using shared global variables within an OpenMP region is generally a bad idea...

Comment: I could solve the segfault error by changing the compiler. I was compiling with icc, (ICC) 2021.6.0 20220226, but now, with g++-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0 its working perfectly. No change in the code

Comment: No longer having a segfault does not mean that the code is correct. It is not, there's no way you can get correct results with the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `omp` loop, all variables at the left side of `=` should be private, such as `ds`, `s`, `B`, `B_left`, `B_right` and `mid`. Segmentation fault is most likely caused by array accessing out-of-bound. The array definitions are not shown, so cannot tell what's wrong. You can debug it with `gdb`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I guess `_station_r_t_midfault[irr] = ...` would work even if `_station_r_t_midfault` is not private if all threads wrote to different `irr` positions?

Comment: All ```Phi```, ```ux```, ```uy```, etc. are shared in the inner loop. It could be a problem to assign values to the same address at the same time by different threads. You'd better do ```omp``` parallelization to the inner loop, or use a unique array for each thread.

Comment: Yes, I'm with you on that. That's why I wrote the comment under the question about the probable race condition. I just wanted to double check that `_station_r_t_midfault[irr] = ...` would be ok although `_station_r_t_midfault` is not private _if_ each thread only wrote to its own positions in the array. OPs code writes to the same positions in all threads which looks like a clear race to me.

Comment: An answer that says "[I] cannot tell what's wrong" is not an answer. You should have posted this as a comment.